# Someone who uses idioms excessively

Tags: idioms, epithet-requests

Is there a term for someone who uses clichés (e.g. right off the bat, lowest hanging fruit, living under a rock) excessively (but correctly)?

To clarify the confusion in the comments: I'm referring to someone who in addition to speaking idiomatically (ie like native speakers do), uses idioms far more often than the average native speaker does.

Comment: You mean someone who speaks idiomatically?

Comment: Yes. Should I rephrase the question?

Comment: Then that would be a fluent speaker.

Comment: Agreed with @TusharRaj, "To **speak a language idiomatically** is to speak it in accordance with native speaker norms. Two aspects of native speaker norms are addressed. One concerns the appropriateness of language to the context of use and to the speaker’s conceptualization. The other concerns language-internal relations, as manifested in particular by preferred collocations and colligations".
(http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199290802.001.0001/acprof-9780199290802-chapter-5)

Comment: Perhaps, he is showing off his speaking skill!

Comment: The keyword here is "excessively" to the point of annoying the listeners.

Comment: @mansour are listeners less likely to be annoyed by someone who speaks unidiomatically?

Comment: @Eilia speaking in idioms is not the same as speaking idiomatically.

Comment: I suspect that you **don’t** mean someone who speaks idiomatically (that means someone who speaks the language like native speakers do), but rather someone who excessively uses fixed phrases and clichéd sayings and proverbs in their speech, right?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Correct. I edited the question.

Comment: [*Idiomaniac*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=SWOvAAAAIAAJ&q=idiomaniac&dq=idiomaniac&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Z9GCVfXbCsjXsAWeqoHwAQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ) perhaps ?

Comment: Mrs. Ulgine Barrows.

Answer (score 10):

The examples you give are not just idioms but clichés, i.e., stale and thus moribund metaphors. One who utters them to excess is a *cliché-monger.* The term is not a common one but is listed in the OED, with two examples from 1947 & 1962, though without its own explicit definition.

Comment: +1 . The greatest of all students of clichés was James Joyce, whose Ulysses has a 72-page section that consists of almost nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

A colorful speaker?

Comment: In the context of language, colorful is a euphemism for vulgar.

Comment: @Tushar yes but not necessarily. It can just mean very expressive.

Comment: 'colorful' sounds like a compliment, but the OP is looking for something towards the negative side.

Comment: @Mitch.  Ah.  Okay, I'll change that to "overly colorful."

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use *stylistically*.

If a person uses many figures of speech(for ex: idioms, similes, metaphors), you can say that he speaks *stylistically*.

You can also say, "He speaks *pompously*" if you know that the person you're referring to is egotistic and uses flowery language to show off his knowledge.

*Extravagance in speech* also refers to the same idea(but has a slight negative connotation).

Answer (score 0):

The things you are describing are figures of speech. A person who uses a lot of figures of speech speaks figuratively.

[figurative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/figurative)

*adjective*

> - of the nature of or involving a figure of speech, especially a metaphor; metaphorical and not literal
> - abounding in or fond of figures of speech.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Also, whether you want to classify them as cliches, idioms, or figures of speech it doesn't really change OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

A *[hack](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hack#hack-2)*:

> noun
>
> 1 A writer or journalist producing dull, unoriginal work:
>   <sub>ODO</sub>

The word could easily extend from its normal usage for writing to cover all forms of *[hackneyed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hackneyed)* communication:

> adjective
>
> (Of a phrase or idea) having been overused;
>   <sub>ODO</sub>

*Whether he is writing or talking, Joe is a **hack**, who can't weave two original words together in a sentence.*

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but the OP may have been referring to someone who speaks in "glittering generalities" or mere "platitudes". Thus, the person speaking in cliche could be referred to as "platitudinous".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"**The master of the cliché**" an ironic honorific

"**Captain Cliché**" - more irony and more direct - following the [Captain Obvious][1] pattern.

[1]: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Captain_Obvious#:~:text=Captain%20Obvious%20(plural%20not%20attested,quotations%20%E2%96%BC

Answer (score 0):

I think the probability is high that they are less concerned with the efficiency of their speech, and more concerned with the aesthetic of their speech. Perhaps, *wordsmith*?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).